Copying files from one SharePoint library to another
I want to copy files from one SharePoint site library folder to a different SharePoint site library folder. I also want all metadata in colums to follow as well. I also want all modifications in file content, metadata in colums and deleted files to update as well.
I want to use Power Automate, I tried "When a file is created or modified (properties only)" and "Create a file" but it doesn't work.
Any tips on what trigger and actions I should use?
Thanks in advance for your help :)

Can you describe what exactly doesn't work? Are you getting an error message?
